# How to add toolbar and pager to custom product collection in magento?

Tags: pagination, toolbar, pager

my `local/mage/catalog/prodoct/newwall.php`

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
   if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {

      $brand_id = $_GET['brand_id'];
      $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()           
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => $brand_id ))
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
      $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    }

      return $collection;

}
```

**I Added cms page layout**

```
 <reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_newall" name="product_new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
      <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar"  template="catalog/product /list/toolbar.phtml">
         <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
      </block>
      <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Please tell me How To add default magento toolbar and pager. using this code display only product.

Comment: is product listing working??

Comment: Yes Working Properlly. But I don't How to get toolbar or pager. Also Work my custom block here properly.

Comment: where did you add the layout update in `cms.xml` ?

Comment: add content => Layout Update XML => I am Adding Xml File

Comment: where did you add that code? Means which layout update xml file ?

Comment: I just Want to Know What code does in newwall.php get toolbar and pager. product list working Very fine

Comment: I am Adding Code In Cms Page Layout Update XML

Comment: i guess that you file location is working local/mage/catalog/prodoct/newwall.php  to local/mage/block/catalog/prodoct/newwall.php

Comment: please show `list.phtml` content

Comment: It's Defulat magento list.phtml

Comment: @amit Bera My file working properly. but I want To Know How set page and toolbar in file. give code or any tutorial link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found My issue.

```
<reference name="content">
```

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>16</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <!--action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action-->
                <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
```

I am Upding my xml file same as Catlog file. it's Working Here